# Display latest product on home page

Tags: opencart

I've been searching around on Google to find an accurate tutorial that explains how to display products on the home page but so far nothing is working!

The latest products block doesn't work; the only thing that I've managed to get working is a single link to a product which is not very attractive.

Anyone know how to display products, featured products, etc. on the home page?

ps. I'm using Opencart 3.0.3.2

Comment: Just enable it in your Extension/Extension/Modules. Than you must via Design/Layouts setup where you wish to see it. After all you should refresh your modification and clear cache in main admin panel blue gear icon.

Comment: Can not we do it without the Extension / Modules? I mean changing the code. And can you tell the name of that extension / modules

Comment: "Can not we do it without the Extension / Modules?" Why? Just use the built-in module.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can see some screen shots.

**1 - Open Latest Extension:**

[image]

**2 - Install Latest Extension:**

[image]

**3 - Edit Latest Extension:**

[image]

**4 - Fill Name of Module and Enable Latest Extension:**

[image]

**5 - Set Home Page:**

[image]

**6 - Add Here Latest Extension:**

[image]

For a better understanding watch this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSyd7Tx8kxc

Answer (score 1):

We have modules so users with out coding knowledge can use. Follow below step to show products on home page

1. Step #1: Login to admin panel, ex:https://demo.opencart.com/admin/
2. Step #2: Now click on Extensions --> Extensions, you can see on left
   side nav.
3. Step #3: Select Modules, from Choose the extension type
4. Step #4: Install Latest or Featured Module
5. Step #5: Click on Plus Button, and enter no.of products you want to
   show.
6. Step #6: Select status has enable, click on save button (top right)
7. Step #7: Now navigate to Design --> Layouts
8. Step #8: Click on Edit button, opposite to Home
9. Step #9: Select module from drop down and add, it can be Content Top
   or Content Bottom
10. Step $10: Save, and just refresh.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes this working..My latest product show is done but as soon as I click on my product, it does not show the detail page and bring it back to the home page.What's the problem

Comment: Can you please share link?

Comment: https://www.avigems.com/index.php?route=common/home. you click product after return home page.

Comment: strange, need to see code. You can email me, will try to help u

Comment: i sent please check mail

Comment: watch video for better understanding : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSyd7Tx8kxc